# clear(1) after detach in GNU screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I run irssi in screen and I want screen to automatically blank the terminal (scrollback) after detach.  I found out that screen has a command called "blanker" that can clear the screen, but I don't see a way to do it automatically after detach (whether remote or via C-a d).

Answer (score 7):

When you run `screen`, it sends (among other things) the strings defined in the terminal description for starting/stopping full-screen operation.  These are `ti` and `te` (in termcap), `smcup` and `rmcup` (in terminfo).

- When you start screen, or attach to a session, it sends `ti` (`smcup`).
- When you stop screen, or detail from a session, it sends `te` (`rmcup`).

Depending on the terminal description, they may be used to switch xterm (and similar terminals) to/from the *alternate screen*.  For most terminals, switching back to the normal screen from the alternate screen makes it seem as if the full-screen application had been cleared from the screen.  (With xterm, you can switch back and forth using menus: the data is still there until it is cleared).

You *could* force `screen` to always use the alternate screen by

- specifying a particular value for the `term` option, or
- using the termcap/terminfo tweaks to modify the `ti`/`te` (`smcup`/`rmcup`) settings

Either way has drawbacks (because you might run `screen` on a different terminal type), but the latter is more likely to work since it does not interfere with the ability to use special keys (cursor- and function-keys).

If you prefer `screen` to use the alternate screen of the xterm-like terminal, you could add to your `.screenrc` file

```
termcapinfo xterm*|rxvt*  te=\E[?1049l:ti=\E[?1049h:
```

If you would rather *not* use the alternate screen, you could redefine `te` to clear the screen:

```
termcapinfo xterm*|rxvt*  te=\E[H\E[2J:ti=\E[H\E[2J:
```

Further reading:

- [16.3 The termcap command](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Termcap-Syntax) (GNU screen manual)
- [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite) (xterm FAQ)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with urxvt. Found the fix [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=84600):

in .Xdefaults:

```
urxvt*termName: rxvt-256color
```

in .screenrc

```
term rxvt-256color
```